# Redux Action Dispatches but does not map to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have An action That I am trying to use in my component, My FetchPosts() function will work and map to state, but when I use my other Action FetchUserPosts() I can see in the redux dev tools that the action dispatches, but in State nothing is there and the state doesn't change at all.

It could be something with my action but im not sure.

postAction.js

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POSTS, FETCH_POST_FOR_APPROVAL, 
FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER  } from './types';

export const fetchPostsFromUser = (id) => dispatch => {
Promise.all([fetch('http://10.6.254.22:5000/posts/1' + id)])
.then(([res1]) => { 
 return Promise.all([res1.json()]) 
})
.then(([posts]) => dispatch ({
  type: FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER,
  payload: posts
 }));
}
```

Types.js

```
 export const FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER = 'FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER';
```

PostReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POSTS, FETCH_POST_FOR_APPROVAL, 
FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
items: [],
item: {}
}

export default function (state = initialState, action ){
switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
        console.log('currently reducing')
    return{
        ...state, 
        items: action.payload
    } 
    case NEW_POSTS:
        return{
            ...state,
            item: action.payload
        }
    case FETCH_POST_FOR_APPROVAL:
        return{
            ...state,
            items: action.payload
        }
    case FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER:
        return{
            ...state,
            items: action.payload
        }
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

My Component I want the function to work with so i can map the props.

```
class ProfilePostBody extends Component {

 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {
  commentBody: null,
  postId: null,
  giphyUrl: null,
  postPicture: null,
  userId: null,
  userIdto: null,
  userIdName: null,
  userIdtoName:null,
  // postBody: null,
  // giphyUrl: null,
  // userIdto: null,
  // userIdName: null,
  // userIdtoName:'Julio',

  displayGifPicker: false
 }
 }

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.fetchPostsFromUser();
  this.props.fetchPosts();

}



render () {
 return (
  // <Grid item xl={6}>
  <div>
    {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>
      <PostBodyTemplate key={index} postId={post.id}  onSubmit= 
{this.handleSubmit} onChange={e => 
this.handleInputChange(e,post.id,post.userId,post.userIdName)} title= 
{post.title} postBody={post.postBody} 
           giphyUrl = {post.giphyUrl} userWhoPosted={post.userIdName} 
commentBody={post.commentBody} userIdtoName={post.userIdtoName} 
 userIdName={post.userIdName} />
       )} 
</div>
 )
}

}

ProfilePostBody.propTypes = {
fetchPostsFromUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
posts: state.posts.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, fetchPostsFromUser 
}) 
 (ProfilePostBody);
```

fetchPosts will work, but if i comment it out and try just the fetchPostsFromUser() it will not work.

Comment: could you upload your code to sandbox ?

Comment: when the action dispatches, what's the payload look like?

Comment: https://ibb.co/XjLsW8x

Comment: I don't think this solves your issube but i noticed that `this.props.fetchPostsFromUser()` expects an id as an argument which you're not providing in your `componentDidMount`